# c# Importing txt files - only last file is being read

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to write some C# code to import all of the text files from a certain directory and export all of the data in the file(s) to another text file.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you're reading in so we can test it please?

Comment: This is a classic scenario where I start a debug session immediately. Try to do the same.

Comment: @JayGould, sample data ...???

Comment: The text files are set up like so:

T Names

F FName ^Joe^^^

F LName ^Bloggs^^^

F Company ^Company Field^^^

F Notes ^This is the notes field^^^. With the capital letter being on a new line.

Comment: What's the purpose of 'foreach (FileInfo file in files)' and setting the variable 'fileName'? If you are referencing fileName somewhere else, the last file will be the one referenced. Some refactoring would make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

What about this bolded syntax error?

```
File.AppendAllText(LogFileDirectory + @"\ImportedUsers.txt"**, +**" First Name: " + 
    FirstName + " Last Name: " + LastName + " Full Name: " + FullName + " Company: " + 
    Company + " Notes: " + Notes "\n");
```

Comment: That one was a typo, I've made the fix in my post.

Comment: This is likely the cause of the issues. It would make sense that the last file still gets included as that is a different call to the append.

Edit: nvm...was a typo in the post.

Comment: I've fixed the typo in my code and it hasn't solved my issue...could you elaborate?